# Unable to get CURL data using SocketIO in YII2?

Tags: php, websocket, socket.io, yii2

URL :- http://localhost:2121/?type=publish&content=testing&to=1191
I am using [this](https://github.com/krissss/yii2-web-msg-sender) extension to add web push notifications.

Till now I have easily configured it properly without any errors but I am unable to get post data in socket function through which I am unable to proceed.

**Sending data using GuzzleHttp :-**

```
  $pushApiUrl = $this->webMsgSender->getPushApiClientUrl(); // http://localhost:2121/
        $response = (new \GuzzleHttp\Client())->post($pushApiUrl, [
            'form_params' => [
                'content' => $msg,
                'to' => $to,
                'type' => $data->type ?? 'publish',
            ],
        ]);
```

**A function where I need $_POST data:-**

```
  // When $socketIo is started, it listens to an http port, through which data can be pushed to any uid or all uids
        $this->socketIo->on('workerStart', function () {
            // listen to an http port
            echo "I am listeining to ".$this->webMsgSender->getPushApiServerUrl();
            $innerHttpWorker = new Worker($this->webMsgSender->getPushApiServerUrl());
            // Triggered when the http client sends data
            $innerHttpWorker->onMessage = function (TcpConnection $httpConnection,$data) {
                $uidConnectionMap = $this->globalData['uidConnectMap'];
                $requestParams = $_POST ?: $_GET;
                // URL format of push data type=publish&to=uid&content=xxxx
                $model = new ClientSendModel(['socketIo' => $this->socketIo]);
                echo 'requestParams';
                echo PHP_EOL;
                print_R($requestParams);//NOT WORKING
                echo PHP_EOL;
                print_R($_REQUEST);//NOT WORKING
                if ($model->load($requestParams, '') && $model->validate()) {
                    if ($model->to && !isset($uidConnectionMap[$model->to])) {
                        return $httpConnection->send('offline');
                    }
                    $model->send();
                    return $httpConnection->send('ok');
                }
                return $httpConnection->send('fail');
            };
            
            $innerHttpWorker->listen();
        });
```

Laravel example [link](https://developpaper.com/laravel-integrates-phpsocket-io-to-implement-web-message-push/):-

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out

````
 ```$innerHttpWorker->onMessage = function (TcpConnection $httpConnection,$request) {
            $uidConnectionMap = $this->globalData['uidConnectMap'];
            $requestParams = $_POST ?: $_GET;
            $this->webMsgSender->logger('requestParams');
            $this->webMsgSender->logger($requestParams);
            $this->webMsgSender->logger($_SERVER ??'EMPTY SERVER VARIABLE');
            $this->webMsgSender->logger('workerStart_data');
            $this->webMsgSender->logger('TcpConnection');
            $this->webMsgSender->logger($request->post());
            echo "I AM HERE";
            print_R($request->post());```
````

`$innerHttpWorker->onMessage = function (TcpConnection $httpConnection,$request) {`
Now `$request->post()` contains the data